# Implicit declaration of 'distanceBetweenPoints' is invalid in C99

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

The following code:

```
CGFloat currentDistance =  distanceBetweenPoints(firstTouch,secondTouch);
```

gives me this error: *Implicit declaration of 'distanceBetweenPoints' is invalid in C99*

`firstTouch` and `secondTouch` are `CGPoint`s

```
    CGPoint firstTouch = [tOne locationInView:[tOne view]];
    CGPoint secondTouch = [tTwo locationInView:[tTwo view]];
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: This site is for reviews of working code. It's not for finding out why your code does not work. Questions like this belong on Stack Overflow (though in the future you should take care to provide a short but complete code sample that demonstrates your problem - the snippet you provided here, for example, does not show which header files you included, which is of course relevant to the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're using a very old version of Cocos2D? I only know this method by the name of `ccpDistance`. See: http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/_c_g_point_extension_8h.html#a76b1b389db811d00e0a461df630d9a8e

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
#include "CGPointUtils.h"
```

somewhere in your source file before you try to call `distanceBetweenPoints`.